# Finding the Hessian matrix of this function

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, sympy, convex-optimization

Hi I have the following function:

sum from 1 to 5000 -log(1−(xi)^2) -log(1-(a_i)^t*x), where a_i is a random vector and we are trying to minimize this function's value via Netwon's method.

I need a way to calculate the Hessian matrix with respect to (x1, x2, x3, ...). I tried auto-gradient but it took too much time. Here is my current time.

```
from autograd import elementwise_grad as egrad
from autograd import jacobian
import autograd.numpy as np

x=np.zeros(5000);
a = np.random.rand(5000,5000)
def f (x):
  sum = 0;
  for i in range(5000):
      sum += -np.log(1 - x[i]*x[i]) - np.log(1-np.dot(x,a[i]))
  
  return sum;

df = egrad(f)
d2f = jacobian(egrad(df)); 
print(d2f(x));
```

I have tried looking into sympy but I am confused on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regular `NumPy` vectorization array operations which will speed up significantly the execution of the program:

```
from autograd import elementwise_grad as egrad
from autograd import jacobian
import autograd.numpy as np
from time import time
import datetime


n = 5000
x = np.zeros(n)
a = np.random.rand(n, n)

f = lambda x: -1 * np.sum(np.log(1-x**2) + np.log(1-np.dot(a, x)))

t_start = time()
df = egrad(f)
d2f = jacobian(egrad(df))
t_end = time() - t_start
print('Execution time: ', datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t_end).strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
```

**Output**

```
Execution time: 02:02:27
```

In general, every time you deal with numeric data, you should avoid by all means using `loops` for calculations, as they usually become the bottleneck of the program due to the their header and the maintenance of the counter variable.

`NumPy` on the other hand, uses a very short header for each `array`, and is highly optimized, as you'd expect, for numeric calculations.

Note the `x**2` which squares every item of `x` instead of `x[i]*x[i]`, and the `np.dot(a, x)` which performs the `np.dot(x, a[i])` in just one command (where `x` and `a` switch places to fit the required dimensions).

You can refer to [this](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.00-introduction-to-numpy.html) great e-book which will explain this point in a greater detail.

Cheers

Comment: Ok it seems I made a mistake in the post the problem isn't computing the Hessian function, but evaluating it for a specify x. Like when I try to print(df(x)) it takes took long

Answer (score 1):

PyTorch has a GPU optimised [`hessian`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.autograd.functional.hessian) operation:

```py
import torch

torch.autograd.functional.hessian(func, inputs)
```